# Помогите, с заданием

Tags: c#, методы, switch

Нужно, чтобы в кейсах можно было взаимодействовать в имеющимися у меня методами. То есть, когда выбираешь, например, увеличить или уменьшить остаток, в обоих кейсах считало из метода. Я понятия не имею, как подключить методы в мeйне.

```
public enum Bank_name { Sberbank, VTB24, Avangard}; // перечисления банков

class Schetvbanke // класс счет в банке
{
    public int Number; // номер
    public double ostatok; // остаток
    public Bank_name Name; // банк

    // конструктор
    public Schetvbanke(int Number, double ostatok, Bank_name Name)
    {
        this.Number = Number;
        this.ostatok = ostatok;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}

class Program // рабочий класс
{
    public static void New_ostatok(Schetvbanke ost1, double newostatok) // передача нового остатка в метод
    {
        ost1.ostatok = newostatok;
    }

    public static void Percent(Schetvbanke ost1, int percent, char dir) // процент от остатка
    {
        double perc = ost1.ostatok * percent / 100; // процент от числа (остатка)
        if (dir == 'p') // для увеличения суммы
            ost1.ostatok = ost1.ostatok + perc;
        else if (dir == 'm') // для уменьшения суммы
            ost1.ostatok = ost1.ostatok - perc;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) // точка входа
    {
        Schetvbanke schet1 = new Schetvbanke(1232342, 50, Bank_name.VTB24); // создание первого типа
        //schet1.Name = Bank_name.VTB24;
        Schetvbanke schet2 = new Schetvbanke(445453, 340, Bank_name.Avangard); // второй тип
        //schet2.Name = Bank_name.Avangard;
        Schetvbanke schet3 = new Schetvbanke(87654332, 0, Bank_name.Sberbank); // третий тип
        //schet3.Name = Bank_name.Sberbank;

        bool exit = false;
        while (exit == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите счет:\n\t1. Имя: {0}, Номер: {1}, Остаток: {2}\n\t2. Имя: {3}, Номер: {4}, Остаток: {5}\n\t3. Имя: {6}, Номер: {7}, Остаток: {8}", 
                schet1.Name, schet1.Number, schet1.ostatok, schet2.Name, schet2.Number, schet2.ostatok, schet3.Name, schet3.Number, schet3.ostatok );
            int chooseSchet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Выберите операцию:\n\t1. Задать остаток\n\t2. Увеличить/уменьшить на %\n\t3. Выход");
            int chooseAction = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (chooseAction)
            {
                case 1: // остаток
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case 2: // проценты
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Выберите операцию:\n\t1. Увеличить\n\t2. Уменьшить");
                        int chActPercent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        switch (chActPercent)
                        {
                            case 1: // увеличить
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            case 2: // уменьшить
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Неправильно выбрано действие!");
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Неправильно выбрано действие!");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Извините что не по теме. Что за "вырвиглазные" названия переменных и классов

Comment: Советую почитать правила оформления кода, например [ЗДЕСЬ](https://habr.com/post/26077/). А то черт ногу сломит с такими названиями.

Comment: Можете поставить конкретную задачу я поправлю ваш код до адекватного состояния. В чём ваша задача заключается и что не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

[image: пример работы программы]

```
/// <summary>
/// Банки
/// </summary>
enum BankType
{
    Sberbank,
    VTB24,
    Avangard
}

/// <summary>
/// Счет в банке
/// </summary>
class Account
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public BankType Bank { get; private set; }
    //сумма счета
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }

    //ctor
    public Account(BankType bankType, int number, decimal amount)
    {
        Bank = bankType;
        Number = number;
        Amount = amount;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Положить на счет
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">сумма для начисления</param>
    /// <returns>true if OK</returns>
    public bool Deposit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount < 1.00M)
        {
            var message = "Ошибка операции:" +
                "сумма начисления не может быть меньше одного рубля!";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            return false;
        }

        Amount += amount;

        return true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Снять со счета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">сумма для снятия</param>
    /// <returns>true if OK</returns>
    public bool Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount < 1.00M)
        {
            var message = "Ошибка операции:" +
                "сумма снятия не может быть меньше одного рубля!";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            return false;
        }

        if (amount > Amount)
        {
            var message = "Ошибка операции:" +
                "сумма снятия превышает сумму текущего счета!";
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            return false;
        }

        Amount -= amount;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Класс для сообщений и пользовательского ввода

```
static class AppView
{
    public enum OperationType
    {
        Exit, //выход из программы
        Deposit, //положить на счет
        Withdraw, //взять со счета
        SelectOtherAccount, //выбрать другой счет
        ShowAllAccounts, //показать список всех счетов
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод списка всех счетов
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accounts"></param>
    public static void ListAccounts(List<Account> accounts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ваши счета:");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('_', 60));
        Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,20} {2,20}", "Банк", "Сумма на счете", "Номер счета");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));

        foreach (var acc in accounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,17:C} {2,20}", acc.Bank, acc.Amount, acc.Number);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('_', 60));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение номера счета
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>номер счета или -1 при неправильном вводе</returns>
    public static int GetAccountNumber()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Укажите номер счета или \"0\" для выхода и нажмите клавишу \"Ввод\"");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
        {
            //если удалось спарсить число, возвращаем его
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Сообщение об окончании работы
    /// </summary>
    public static void End()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Работа программы завершена. Спасибо.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Сообщение об ошибочном номере счета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accNumber"></param>
    public static void AccountNotFound(int accNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Счета с номером {0} не существует!", accNumber);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод данных по рабочему счету
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="account"></param>
    public static void CurrentStateAccount(Account account)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Текущий рабочий счет:");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('_', 60));
        Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,20} {2,20}", "Банк", "Сумма на счете", "Номер счета");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 60));

        Console.WriteLine("{0,6} {1,17:C} {2,20}", account.Bank, account.Amount, account.Number);

        Console.WriteLine(new string('_', 60));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выяснение дальнейших действий
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static OperationType GetOperation()
    {
        int index = -1;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Вы желаете: Выйти-""0"", Внести-""1"", Снять-""2"", Другой счет-""3"", Список счетов-""4""");
            var input = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            switch (input)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D0:
                    index = 0;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    index = 1;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    index = 2;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D3:
                    index = 3;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D4:
                    index = 4;
                    break;
                default:
                    index = -1;
                    break;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine();
            if (index < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Неверный выбор. Попробуйте еще раз.");
            }

        } while (index < 0);

        return (OperationType)index;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Запрос у пользователя суммы для начисления или снятия
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="forDeposit">true если для начисления</param>
    /// <returns>сумма или -1 при неправильном вводе</returns>
    public static decimal GetAmount(bool forDeposit)
    {
        if (forDeposit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Введите сумму начисления на счет или ""0"" и нажмите ""Ввод""");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Введите сумму для снятия со счета или ""0"" и нажмите ""Ввод""");
        }

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        decimal result;
        if (decimal.TryParse(input, out result))
        {
            //если удалось спарсить число, возвращаем его
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowWrongAmount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введена неверная сумма.");
    }

    public static void ShowSuccessDeposit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Успешно начислено на счет.");
    }

    public static void ShowUnsuccessfulDeposit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка начисления на счет.");
    }

    public static void ShowSuccessWithdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Успешно cнято со счета.");
    }

    public static void ShowUnsuccessfulWithdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка снятия со счета.");
    }
}
```

И основная реализация алгоритма

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Account(BankType.Avangard, 12345, 234001.85M),
            new Account(BankType.Sberbank, 123986, 554010.70M),
            new Account(BankType.VTB24, 5697054, 4001.34M),
        };

        //задаем кодировку, чтоб символ рубля отображался правильно
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        //выводим счета
        AppView.ListAccounts(accounts);

        //текущий рабочий счет
        Account account = null;

        //спрашиваем какой счет выбирает пользователь
        //в результате вернется тип операции, а account получит значение
        AppView.OperationType operation = SelectAccount(accounts, ref account);

        //если пользователь не выбрал счет, а выход из программы
        if (operation == AppView.OperationType.Exit)
        {
            AppView.End();
            return;
        }

        //рабочий цикл хождений по выбору операций
        do
        {
            //запросим пользователя о дальнейших действиях
            operation = AppView.GetOperation();

            switch (operation)
            {
                case AppView.OperationType.Deposit:
                    MakeDeposit(account);
                    AppView.CurrentStateAccount(account);
                    break;
                case AppView.OperationType.Withdraw:
                    MakeWithdraw(account);
                    AppView.CurrentStateAccount(account);
                    break;
                case AppView.OperationType.ShowAllAccounts:
                    AppView.ListAccounts(accounts);
                    AppView.CurrentStateAccount(account);
                    break;
                case AppView.OperationType.SelectOtherAccount:
                    AppView.ListAccounts(accounts);
                    operation = SelectAccount(accounts, ref account);
                    break;
            }

        } while (operation != AppView.OperationType.Exit);

        //прощальные слова
        AppView.End();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выбор рабочего счета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accounts">список счетов</param>
    /// <param name="account">ссылка на рабочий счет</param>
    /// <returns>Print.OperationType.ShowAllAccounts говорит о том, что счет выбран</returns>
    private static AppView.OperationType SelectAccount(List<Account> accounts, ref Account account)
    {
        //выясняем с каким счетом хотим работать
        account = GetAccount(accounts);
        //проверяем
        if (account == null)
        {
            //значит пользователь выбрал выход из программы
            return AppView.OperationType.Exit;
        }

        //выведем данные по выбранному счету
        AppView.CurrentStateAccount(account);

        return AppView.OperationType.ShowAllAccounts;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Операция начисления на счет
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="account">сумма начисления</param>
    private static void MakeDeposit(Account account)
    {
        decimal amount = -1;
        do
        {
            amount = AppView.GetAmount(forDeposit: true);

            if (amount < 0) AppView.ShowWrongAmount();

        } while (amount < 0);

        //если пользователь передумал делать начисление на счет
        if (amount == 0) return;

        if (account.Deposit(amount))
        {
            AppView.ShowSuccessDeposit();
        }
        else
        {
            AppView.ShowUnsuccessfulDeposit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Операция снятия со счета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="account">сумма снятия</param>
    private static void MakeWithdraw(Account account)
    {
        decimal amount = -1;
        do
        {
            amount = AppView.GetAmount(forDeposit: false);

            if (amount < 0) AppView.ShowWrongAmount();

        } while (amount < 0);

        //если пользователь передумал делать начисление на счет
        if (amount == 0) return;

        if (account.Withdraw(amount))
        {
            AppView.ShowSuccessWithdraw();
        }
        else
        {
            AppView.ShowUnsuccessfulWithdraw();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение рабочего счета
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accounts">список счетов</param>
    /// <returns>выбранный счет или null</returns>
    private static Account GetAccount(List<Account> accounts)
    {
        Account result = null;
        int accNumber = -1;

        do
        {
            //просим указать номер счета
            accNumber = AppView.GetAccountNumber();
            //если ввели 0 для выхода
            if (accNumber == 0) break;

            //пытаемся найти счет с таким номером
            //если нашли, то выходим из цикла
            if (TryGetAccount(accounts, accNumber, out result)) break;

            //сообщаем что не нашли такой
            AppView.AccountNotFound(accNumber);
            accNumber = -1;

        } while (accNumber < 0);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Поиск счета по номеру
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accounts">список счетов</param>
    /// <param name="accNumber">номер искомого счета</param>
    /// <param name="account">выходной результат экземл. счета</param>
    /// <returns>true if OK</returns>
    private static bool TryGetAccount(List<Account> accounts, int accNumber, out Account account)
    {
        bool result = false;
        account = null;

        foreach (var acc in accounts)
        {
            //если нашли с таким номером
            if (acc.Number == accNumber)
            {
                result = true;
                account = acc;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/FKIRRStec8GykA)